# Haskell profiling understanding cost centre summary for anonymous lambda

Tags: haskell, profiling

I'm trying to profile my medium size compiler written in Haskell. When running it on an example file, I get the following profiling data:

```
vehicle +RTS -po.profiling/vehicle-1706073721 -p -RTS compile --target MarabouQueries --specification vehicle/tests/golden/compile/acasXu/spec.vcl --network acasXu:vehicle/tests/golden/compile/acasXu/fake.onnx

    total time  =        0.72 secs   (716 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 1,558,506,104 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE             MODULE                                          SRC                                                                       %time %alloc

fmap                    Vehicle.Prelude.Logging.Backend                 src/Vehicle/Prelude/Logging/Backend.hs:49:13-19                            19.7   21.2
runVehicle.\            Vehicle                                         src/Vehicle.hs:(56,46)-(67,52)                                             12.2   19.3
fmap                    Vehicle.Prelude.Supply                          src/Vehicle/Prelude/Supply.hs:28:13-19                                      9.1    8.2
compileDecls            Vehicle.Backend.Queries                         src/Vehicle/Backend/Queries.hs:(87,1)-(101,47)                              5.7    7.2
$mRelevantExplicitArg.\ Vehicle.Syntax.AST.Arg                          src/Vehicle/Syntax/AST/Arg.hs:51:36-60                                      5.6    5.4
>>=                     Vehicle.Prelude.Logging.Backend                 src/Vehicle/Prelude/Logging/Backend.hs:49:35-39                             4.3    2.9
fmap                    Vehicle.Compile.Context.Free.Instance           src/Vehicle/Compile/Context/Free/Instance.hs:24:13-19                       4.3    4.2
>>=                     Vehicle.Prelude.Supply                          src/Vehicle/Prelude/Supply.hs:28:35-39                                      3.2    2.9
>>=                     Vehicle.Prelude.Logging.Instance                src/Vehicle/Prelude/Logging/Instance.hs:49:35-39                            2.8    4.4
pure                    Vehicle.Prelude.Supply                          src/Vehicle/Prelude/Supply.hs:28:22-32                                      2.2    0.7
return                  Vehicle.Prelude.Logging.Backend                 src/Vehicle/Prelude/Logging/Backend.hs:49:35-39                             2.2    3.6
return                  Vehicle.Compile.Context.Free.Instance           src/Vehicle/Compile/Context/Free/Instance.hs:24:35-39                       2.2    1.5
```

Looking at the second entry, the function `runVehicle` (which is directly called from my main function) is as follows:

```hs
runVehicle :: (MonadStdIO IO) => Options -> IO ()
runVehicle Options {..} = do
  withLogger globalOptions $ \logSettings -> do
    case modeOptions of
      Nothing ->
        fatalError
          "No mode provided. Please use one of 'typeCheck', 'compile', 'verify', 'check', 'export'"
      Just mode -> case mode of
        Check options -> typeCheck logSettings options
        Compile options -> compile logSettings options
        Verify options -> verify logSettings options
        Validate options -> validate logSettings options
        Export options -> export logSettings options
```

My understanding is that the cost-centre denotes the time spent executing the function, excluding the time spent executing the functions it calls. The entry in the cost centre summaries seems to suggest that 12.2% of the time is spent executing the anonymous lambda.

I don't understand how that can be the case, as all it's doing is a simple case split. Does anyone have a good explanation for what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My understanding is that the cost-centre denotes the time spent executing the function, excluding the time spent executing the functions it calls.

I don't think this is correct. I think a more correct version is that the time assigned to a cost center denotes time spent executing that cost center, excluding the time assigned to **cost centers** it calls. If there are no functions it calls that are themselves cost centers, then the parent gets assigned all the cost. Perhaps that is what is happening to you, i.e., perhaps `typeCheck`, `compile`, and friends are not cost centers.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely cause is that one of the functions doing the actual work has not been assigned a cost center.  Be warned that if you are using `-fprof-auto` to assign cost centers (a common default when Cabal or Stack is managing the profiling), then functions marked `INLINE` are not assigned cost centers by default.

For example, if the following program:

```
foo :: Int
{-# INLINE foo #-}
foo = sum [1..10000000000]

bar :: Maybe Int -> IO ()
bar = \mx -> case mx of
  Nothing -> print foo
  Just x -> print (x + foo)

main = bar (Just 5)
```

is compiled and run under Stack with:

```
stack build --profile
stack exec --profile main -- +RTS -p
```

then the profile will attribute the cost of the calculation in the inlined function `foo` to the anonymous lambda:

```
    Wed Jan 24 13:55 2024 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       main +RTS -p -RTS

    total time  =        5.00 secs   (5004 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc =      49,488 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE           SRC                       %time %alloc

bar.\       Main             Profile.hs:(6,14)-(8,27)  100.0   21.9
MAIN        MAIN             <built-in>                  0.0    1.3
CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.FD <entire-module>             0.0   70.2
CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding  <entire-module>             0.0    4.9
CAF         GHC.Conc.Signal  <entire-module>             0.0    1.3
```

Without the `INLINE` directive, costs are attributed as expected:

```
    Wed Jan 24 13:58 2024 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       main +RTS -p -RTS

    total time  =        4.89 secs   (4895 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc =      49,488 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE           SRC                       %time %alloc

foo         Main             Profile.hs:2:1-26         100.0    0.0
CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding  <entire-module>             0.0    4.9
MAIN        MAIN             <built-in>                  0.0    1.3
CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.FD <entire-module>             0.0   70.2
CAF         GHC.Conc.Signal  <entire-module>             0.0    1.3
bar.\       Main             Profile.hs:(5,14)-(7,27)    0.0   21.8
```